# Rails: Capyabra / Selenium Chrome-Driver Settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have my `Rails-App` set up with `Capybara`. Tests are working fine but I'm getting this error:

> 2019-05-03 14:51:58 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.

**Gemfile**

```
group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
```

**test_helper.rb**
(with or without the disabled lines makes no difference)

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  #   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :chrome,
  #                                  options: Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: %w[headless disable-gpu])
  # end
  # Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
  Kernel.srand config.seed
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not an error,it is a deprecation warning.

The gem `chromedriver-helper` is [deprecated](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper)

> NOTICE: This gem is out of support as of 2019-03-31 Please use
>   https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers instead. See
>   https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper/issues/83 for
>   details.

In you gemfile:

```
group :test do
     gem 'webdrivers', '~> 3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'capybara'
end
```

I'll suggest you to move capybara in the development and test's group, and also update it, if is possible.

Answer (score 7):

this worked for me. Since the gem is deprecated, I just uninstalled the gem

```
 gem uninstall chromedriver-helper
```

then remove it from your gem file and run:

```
bundle update
```

after that, add the webdriver gem in-place, and bundle install

```
gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0'

bundle install
```

the warnings should be gone

Answer (score 3):

I had this concern when working on a **Rails 6** application in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

The issue is that the [chrome-helper](https://rubygems.org/gems/chromedriver-helper) gem is deprecated. Its last version was  **2.1.1** in March 24, 2019.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Simply replace the [chrome-helper](https://rubygems.org/gems/chromedriver-helper) gem with the [webdrivers](https://rubygems.org/gems/webdrivers) gem in your `Gemfile`:

So instead of this:

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
```

You will have this:

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```

Then install the gem using:

```
bundle install
```

This will update your `Gemfile.lock` will the [webdrivers](https://rubygems.org/gems/webdrivers) gem and remove the [chrome-helper](https://rubygems.org/gems/chromedriver-helper) gem from it as well.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**