# An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require_relative '../config/environment'

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `driver_path=' for Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome:Module
# /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/chromedriver-helper-2.1.1/lib/chromedriver-helper.rb:4:in `<main>'
# /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
# /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
# ./config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:4:in `require_relative'
# ./config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require_relative'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. Unable to find problem.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and format your error. Then add relevant informations and code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This answer might help. [Another same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970418/rails-capyabra-selenium-chrome-driver-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the good dependencies on your systems :)